# iterating a numpy matrix, and assign its rows with information from other dataframe and numpy array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy

I have a matrix, e.g., defined as `x_matrix = np.zeros(200,16)`   Iterating over the rows, I need to assign each row of this matrix with two component vectors, `a1` is an array with 10 elements, `a2` is a corresponding row belonging to a pandas dataframe `y_dataframe`  `y_dataframe` has shape of `(200,6)`

I can iterate the matrix as follows. But I also need the row number of x_matrix to retreive the corresponding row in the y_dataframe. Are there other ways to iterate the matrix rows, and compose its rows with different component vectors described as above.

```
for row in x_matrix
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this without iteration if you wish using `np.repeat` and `np.hstack`:

```py
# assuming `a1` is shaped (10,) i.e. 1D array
a1_repeated = np.repeat(a1[np.newaxis, :], 200, axis=0)

x_matrix = np.hstack((a1_repeated, y_dataframe))
```

where we first convert `a1` into a row vector of shape `(10, 1)` via `[np.new_axis, :]`, then `repeat` it `200` times row-wise (`axis=0`). Lastly we `h`orizontally `stack` this `(200, 10)` shaped `a1_repeated` and `y_dataframe` to get an array of shape `(200, 16)`.

But if you want to iterate, `enumerate` gives you index you are at:

```py
for row_number, row in enumerate(x_matrix):
    x_matrix[row_number] = [*a1, *y_dataframe.iloc[row_number]]
```

where `y_dataframe.iloc[row_number]` is equal to `a2` you mention i.e. a row of dataframe.